# \protect'ing a token list

Tags: macros, expansion

To prevent expansion of a macro in expansion contexts we can define the macro as `\protected`. I'm wondering if there's a way to do the same for an arbitrary token list.

So is it possible to define a command `\protecttoks` which can be used like `\protecttoks{<token list>}` and works in the following way:

- In normal execution mode it just inserts `<token list>` in the token stream, such that they can be executed normally.
- In expansion mode it expands to itself, i.e. the unexpanded token list `\protecttoks{<token list>}`.

The idea is to be able to insert literal material into a token list, where the exact number of expansions done on the token list isn't know in advance.

**EDIT:** Perhaps the comment about `\protect` in LaTeX as an example led to confusion, I removed that. The point is to define something that still gives the correct output for `\foo`, even if that command breaks after expansion:

```
\def\foo{\textcolor{blue}{x}}
\edef\bar{\protecttoks{\foo}}

\edef\bar{\bar}
% more calls here ...
\edef\bar{\bar}
\bar
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of a `\protected` macro it is possible to come close to what you want. The basic idea is to start with a `\protected` macro followed by another non-`\protected` macro. In an `\edef` (or `\write` or `\expanded` or...) the `\protected` macro will be skipped by TeX and the other macro will expand leaving itself (preceded by `\noexpand`) and `\unexpanded{<stuff>}`. Everywhere else the `\protected` macro should expand, stripping the unprotected macro and a layer of braces.

The basic setup is:

```
\protected\def\ifsafe#1#2{#2}
\def\elseifunsafe#1{\noexpand\elseifunsafe{\unexpanded{#1}}}
```

then you use as `\ifsafe\elseifunsafe{<stuff>}`. In an `\edef` `\ifsafe` doesn't expand and `\elseifunsafe` does and leaves `\elseifunsafe{<stuff>}`, so you are left with the `\ifsafe\elseifunsafe{<stuff>}` you started with. In other places `\ifsafe` expands consuming the `\elseifunsafe` and the braces around `<stuff>`.

You can define a `\protecting` macro with `\def\protecting{\ifsafe\elseifunsafe}`, but it will disappear after the first `\edef`, leaving the actual protection machinery in place.

A test document:

```
\protected\def\ifsafe#1#2{#2}
\def\elseifunsafe#1{\noexpand\elseifunsafe{\unexpanded{#1}}}

\def\protecting{\ifsafe\elseifunsafe}

\def\tmpa{\protecting{\something undefined}}\show\tmpa
\edef\tmpa{\tmpa 1}\show\tmpa
\edef\tmpa{\tmpa 2}\show\tmpa
\edef\tmpa{\tmpa 3}\show\tmpa

\tt
\detokenize\expandafter{\tmpa}\par
\detokenize\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\tmpa}
\bye
```

prints in the terminal:

```
> \tmpa=macro:
->\protecting {\something undefined}.
l.8 ...protecting{\something undefined}}\show\tmpa

?
> \tmpa=macro:
->\ifsafe \elseifunsafe {\something undefined}1.
l.9 \edef\tmpa{\tmpa 1}\show\tmpa

?
> \tmpa=macro:
->\ifsafe \elseifunsafe {\something undefined}12.
l.10 \edef\tmpa{\tmpa 2}\show\tmpa

?
> \tmpa=macro:
->\ifsafe \elseifunsafe {\something undefined}123.
l.11 \edef\tmpa{\tmpa 3}\show\tmpa

?
```